# How to send object from xml view file to javascript controller file in titanium alloy?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to pass some data as a custom property from this xml to javascript file.


xml file:

```
<ListItem template="menuItemTemplate" itemTitle:text="My Open Tickets"  itemId="openTickets" itemCountContainer:visible="true" itemCount:text="" routeTo="/fulfiller/openCloseTicketsList" argsForController="{\"ticketType\":\"open\"}"></ListItem>
<ListItem template="menuItemTemplate" itemTitle:text="My Close Tickets" itemId="closedTickets" itemCountContainer:visible="true" itemCount:text="" routeTo="/fulfiller/openCloseTicketsList" argsForController='{"ticketType":"open"}'></ListItem>
```

> "routeTo" can be accessed in the js file. But I need to send some custom data to the js file which is json-format object.

```
var argsForController = _.has(item.properties, "argsForController") ? JSON.parse(item.properties.argsForController) : {};

var fileToOpen = item.properties.routeTo
```

I am getting this error. How can I pass an object from XML to javascript?

> Error parsing XML file. element parse error: Error: attribute value
>   must after "="

**This worked fine but does anyone have any better way?**

```
<ListItem template="menuItemTemplate" itemTitle:text="My Open Tickets" itemId="openTickets" itemCountContainer:visible="true" itemCount:text="" routeTo="/fulfiller/openCloseTicketsList" argsForController='{"ticketType":"open"}'></ListItem>
```